Universal Media Server Tree Truncated
I have used Universal Media Server for years.  But I can no longer browse a depth of folders from any renderer.  My media folder tree is multilayered.  The problem is solved if I list a folder directly as shared but I did not need to do that previously.  The GUI has changed over time and I may not understand where I can change a setting to get a great depth of folders that are browsable. Anyone know where the setting may be?
